# Getting an array of checked checkboxes, generated via php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I am dynamically generating a list of multiple checkboxes via php.

```
<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"quetext[]\" value=".$row_all_que['id'].">
```

The button which will post the data to php is disabled in the beginning.

```
<input type="button" value="Next" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="send-que" disabled>
```

I want it to enable when at least one checkbox is checked. How will I do that?

Also, once I am done selecting the required checkboxes, I need to create an array of these checkboxes and pass their value to php.

Edit 1:

Since the data was coming from my server via ajax call, the checkbox elements were getting generated dynamically due to which the code that i had written inside document.ready() was not getting executed.
I shifted my code into the 'success' function of the ajax call and the button enable/disable on checking the checkbox is working fine now.

Here's the jquery code snippet for the ajax call I made:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxData.php",
        data: data,

        success: function(data) {
            $('.quedata').html(data);
            var checkboxes = $('.quedata .ques-box');
            checkboxes.change(function(){
                $('#send-que').prop('disabled', !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
            });
        }
    });
```

Here the 'quedata' class is my tbody element inside which the checkboxes are getting generated.

This is the HTML structure:

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th>Mark(s)</th>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" disabled></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="quedata">
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Edit 2: Solved

Including the code inside the success part of my ajax call solved it and I am getting my desired output. I have posted an answer including the code.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I got the button enable/disable working. I will edit my question and add what I did to achieve it. @Geshode

Comment: Solved the problem.
@Mr.x I had tried that before, but due to the dynamic generation of the checkboxes, it didnt work before. Now it is. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer instead of just an edit to the question - after 48 hours you can accept it to show the problem has been solved.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the checkbox element a little and added a class to it:

```
<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"quetext[]\" class=\"ques-box\" value=".$row_que['id'].">
```

Here's the jquery code snippet for the ajax call I made:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxData.php",
    data: data,

    success: function(data) {
        $('.quedata').html(data);
        var checkboxes = $('.quedata .ques-box');
        checkboxes.change(function(){
            $('#send-que').prop('disabled', !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
        });
    }
});
```

And this is the array generation code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#send-que').click(function(){
        var checked = [];
        $('.ques-box:checked').each(function(){
            checked.push($(this).val());
        });
        for(var i=0; i<checked.length; i++) {
            alert(checked[i]); //Check if values are added
        }
    });
});
```

Sorry for the lack of research before posting, it was my first question on stackoverflow.